# send() failing with EAGAIN after only a few hundred bytes sent

Tags: c, linux, sockets, libev

This is happening on Ubuntu 12.04. The same code works fine on OSX.

In the logs below you can see that SO_SNDBUF is 20440, and several send()s succeed before failing with EAGAIN.

```
wsmux started on port 8888
send buffer size = 20440
open wsmux:187.59.165.86-16580
send 129, result 129, errno 115
message wsmux:187.59.165.86-16580 NICK zxc5239
message wsmux:187.59.165.86-16580 USER zxc zxc zxc zxc
message wsmux:187.59.165.86-16580 JOIN #a
send 2, result 2, errno 115
send 66, result 66, errno 115
send 2, result 2, errno 115
send 42, result 42, errno 115
send 2, result 2, errno 115
send 100, result 100, errno 115
send 2, result 2, errno 115
send 43, result 43, errno 115
send 2, result 2, errno 115
send 48, result 48, errno 115
send 2, result -1, errno 11
close wsmux:187.59.165.86-16580 Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The only socket options enabled are TCP_NODELAY and O_NONBLOCK.
What could be the problem here?

The code in question:

- https://github.com/lessandro/tcpmux/blob/f76217e1507b41da33e572fa025871f9fc38e3eb/src/wsmux.c#L43
- https://github.com/lessandro/sev/blob/13242419b0c9c285f96a84a6b5ee5fad00a2167f/sev.c#L118

Comment: I can't see any successful writes in the log at all. How much data is sent successfully before the first failure?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson 300 bytes would certainly fit in a 20440-byte send buffer, unless getsockopt(SO_SNDBUF) is lying

Comment: Everything was received correctly at the remote end (the 10 packets in the second block)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `O_NONBLOCK` then every call to `send` and `recv` can fail with `EAGAIN`, because you set non-blocking sockets (this only means the calls would block). It's not an error and shouldn't be handled as one. It's explicitly explained in man pages for e.g. `send`.

Comment: Yes. The question is, why would it fail after a few hundred bytes? Clearly there's plenty of space left in the buffer.

Comment: It can get interrupted or anything else that will make kernel not send whole message. It does not matter, either way you have to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`TCP_NODELAY` causes each `send` to send out the data immediately, together with all the TCP/IP headers. If you keep doing that for every 2-bytes packets, you'll quickly run into `EAGAIN` as the remote end have to `ACK` the packets before new ones can be sent. Not to mention it's also very inefficient! Are the 2-bytes packets really urgent?